# Verify that at least some duration has passed using StepVerifier?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, project-reactor

I'm using [reactor-test](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#testing) project and the [StepVerifier](https://projectreactor.io/docs/test/release/api/reactor/test/StepVerifier.html) to test my function, `myFunc`, that returns a `Flux<Result>`:

```java
Flux<Result> results = myFunc()

StepVerifier.create(results). ..
```

Internally `myFunc` is using the [rate-limiter](http://resilience4j.github.io/resilience4j/#_ratelimiter) from [resilience4j](https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j) and I want to verify that *at least* some duration must have passed before the stream is completed using the `StepVerifier`.

How can I do this with the `StepVerifier`?

**Update 1:**

Note that `myFunc()` makes actual calls to a (fake) http server running locally for test purposes. So I think that setting a virtual time is not possible.

**Update 2:**

As an example let's say that `myFunc()` makes 30 requests with the rate-limit configured to 10 rps so I expect the subscription to last for a little more than 3 seconds. I.e. I want to verify that 30 requests were made (`expectNextCount(30)`) and that certain amount of time (3s) must have passed.

Answer (score 1):

To me, it sounds like thenAwait(Duration timeshift)  method is what you're looking for.

```
StepVerifier.Step<T> thenAwait(Duration timeshift)
Pause the expectation evaluation for a given Duration. If a VirtualTimeScheduler has been configured, VirtualTimeScheduler.advanceTimeBy(Duration) will be used and the pause will not block testing or Publisher thread.
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but it doesn't seem to work. If I try `StepVerifier.create(results).thenAwait(Duration.ofMillis(10)).verifyComplete()` then it doesn't fail the test even though it's taking several seconds to complete.

Comment: I see. Apologies for  that I didn't have the option to test it out. However, I don't know if it's intentional but in case it isn't - you've specified 10 milliseconds, which is 1/100 of a single second. I'm not sure it's waiting for more than that and this could mean it is still a passing time. If you want seconds it should be `Duration.ofSeconds(numerOfSeconds).`

Comment: I just wanted to demonstrate a case where I would expect the test to fail (since it's expected to take more than a second) but it didn't.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the clarification! I will look into it some more!

Comment: It seems I've missed an important part: there is a method called `withVirtualTime`. It should be added before using `thenAwait()` Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, but I've update the question to include that `myFunc()` is making http requests to an actual running server. I suppose that this makes using virtual time impossible since then no requests will be made.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is `expectNoEvent(Duration)`. Note that subscription is an event that (almost) always happens, so for an empty sequence you should have something like:

```
StepVerifier.create(result)
    .expectSubscription()
    .expectNoEvent(Duration.ofMillis(100))
    .verifyComplete();
```

Comment: This doesn't work because I am indeed expecting data. For example if I make 30 requests with a rate-limit set to 10 rps then I expect the subscription to last for a little more than 3 seconds. This is what I want to verify. I'll update the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

`verify()` returns a `Duration` object marking the actual duration of the verification. That way you can check how long it took in total.

However, it seems that it doesn't take into account `withVirtualTime` - it will still return the actual duration of the verification, and not the virtual time, which makes it a lot less useful.